# Let $U =\{ p\in \mathbb{P_4}(\mathbb{R}): p(6) = 0 \}$. Find a Basis of $U$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

LADR 3rd ed. S.Axler|Section 2.C|problem 4. page.48

Let $U = \{ p\in \mathbb{P_4}(\mathbb{R}): p(6) = 0 \}$.

I take the general form of a polynomial of degree 4 : 
$p(x)=e+dx^1+cx^2+bx^3+ax^4$
and then I tried to narrow the form down to one that represents polynomials of degree 4 with the property that p(6)=Zero

$0=e+d6^1+c6^2+b6^3+a6^4$
$e=-d6^1-c6^2-b6^3-a6^4$

$p(x)=e+dx^1+cx^2+bx^3+ax^4$ turns into:
$p(x)=d6^1-c6^2-b6^3-a6^4+dx^1+cx^2+bx^3+ax^4$
$p(x)=d(x-6)+c(x^2-6^2)+b(x^3-6^3)+a(x^4-6^4)$

According to a worked-out solution I found on the net, $\{(x-6),(x^2-6^2),(x^3-6^3),(x^4-6^4)\}$ is indeed supposed to be a basis for the subspace described above.

What I fail to understand is how $\{(x-6),(x^2-6^2),(x^3-6^3),(x^4-6^4)\}$ can be linearly independent and thus a basis for the subspace(assuming the answer is correct).

$0=p(\textbf{6})=d(\textbf{6}-6)+c(\textbf{6}^2-6^2)+b(\textbf{6}^3-6^3)+a(\textbf{6}^4-6^4)$

If x=6, then p(x) is zero, but the coefficients do not have to be zero.

Thank you.

Comment: An alternative to the basis $\{(x-6),(x^2-6^2),(x^3-6^3),(x^4-6^4)\}$ is $\{(x-6),(x^2-6x),(x^3-6x^2),(x^4-6x^3)\}$, or rewritten $\{(x-6),x(x-6),x^2(x-6),x^3(x-6)\}$, seen by remembering that any polynomial of degree 4 or less that has $6$ as a root is by the fundamental theorem of algebra able to be written in the form $f(x)=(x-6)q(x)$ where $q(x)$ is some other polynomial of degree at most three, i.e. $f(x)=(x-6)(ax^3+bx^2+cx+d)$ for some real constants $a,b,c,d$.

Comment: @PrithiviRaj: For Readers who voted to close as duplicate, note the current Question focuses on the linear independence of $\{(x-6),\ldots,(x-6)^4\}$.  While this issue is mentioned in the proposed duplicate, it is hand-waved there (not unreasonable for the body of a Question that wants to ask about something else), and the Answer (in suggesting improvements to the reasoning offered in the Question) does not fill this lacuna.  I'm going to vote to reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vectors $\{(x-6),(x^2-6^2),(x^3-6^3),(x^4-6^4)\}$ are linearly independent simply because by definition

$$c_1(x-6)+c_2(x^2-6^2)+c_3(x^3-6^3)+c_4(x^4-6^4)=0\iff c_i=0$$

exactly as for the standard basis $1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4$.

Note that you can't plug in a particular value for x to check linear independence since $1,x, x^2,x^3,x^4$ represent invariable elements/vectors of the vector space $\mathbb{P_4}$.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to prove that $\{x^i-6^i: i=1,\ldots,4\}$ is a linearly independent set. Suppose that $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_4$ are real numbers such that
$$
\sum_{i=i}^4 \alpha_i (x^i-6^i) = \alpha_4x^4+\alpha_3x^3+\alpha_2x^2+\alpha_1x-\left(\sum_{i=1}^4 6^i\right)
$$
is the constant polynomial $0$. Therefore
$$
\alpha_1=\cdots=\alpha_4=0.
$$